# Print a string in a Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows, printing, uwp

So I'm in a bit of a bind here as it seems Windows Universal Apps don't have access to the `System.Drawing` namespace.  I'm building an interactive sign in sheet with an NDA box and a submit button.

The basic idea is that once the person signs in, they can press the submit button and a label printer nearby will print the name the user entered into a pair of text boxes.

I looked at the documentation provided by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app), but this seems to indicate going to some alternative page upon pressing a button.  Is there a way to just print a string variable as with the `PrintDocument` class from the `System.Drawing` namespace?

Comment: Did you take a look at [the Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) ?

Comment: I did, but didn't find the examples provided to be terribly clear on the matter.

Comment: I'd say: create a LabelPage.xaml for your label and see how far you get to printing it. The DrawString is just a detail about how to display text.